# MySQL MariaDB server won't start kali linux

Tags: php, mysql, linux, raspberry-pi, mariadb

I'm working on a project with raspberry pi that has to be super secure, so I needed Kali Linux to do penetration testing. I didn't have anywhere else to install it, so I installed it on the Pi itself.

The project used mysql, so one of the first things I did on bootup was installed the apache2 and php packages necessary.

Then I tried, `apt install mysql-server` like I usually do, and it says it has no installation candidate. I figure that means it isn't in my apt repositories, but I couldn't find a ppa or anything for mysql. I then tried:
`apt-cache search | grep mysql`

and found that there was a package called `default-mysql-server`.

I installed this and then tried `service mysql start`. After a while it will say:

> Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with
> error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe"
> for details.

If needed I can put the output of those commands.

Also, my **/etc/mysql/my.cnf** file looks like this (I  took out the comments because they are rather redundant):

> [client-server]
>
> !includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
>
> !includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/

That is literally all there is. I'm used to there being other entries, but I don't know if this has anything to do with my problem.

Comment: Why would you _not_ post the output of `journalctl -xe`? This will literally tell you exactly what the error was.

Comment: The only reason I didn’t was because it was so long and I was making the post on a different computer (my pi was starting to overheat, so i was letting it cool off).

Comment: Also, the error was saying I had another process running on that socket, which according to some commands I found on other Stack Overflow posts, was not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I wasn’t getting any answers, so I tried something different. Originally I didn’t want to install the kali-linux-full package, because it would take up so much space, but I figured it would have MySQL preinstalled, so I went ahead and installed it. Everything is working now!